# Import namespaces automatically into all cshtml files in App_Code folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

For some reason for all my `.cshtml` files in `App_Code` folder I have to explicitly import namespaces with `@using Namespace` directive.

However, I do not have to do that for any `.cshtml` view that is located in the `Views` folder because I have added the needed namespaces to the `web.config` file in the Views folder.

So, is there a similar way to add the desired namespaces so they will be automtically imported into the files residing in `App_Code` folder as well?

EDIT: What's in `App_Code` folders are *not* views, but supporting `.cshtml` files containing primarily `@helper`s.

Comment: Can App_Code folder have a web.config?

Comment: @Nkosi don't know, so that's what I am asking.

Comment: The underlying question is *why do you have views NOT in a views folder*?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Those aren't views. cshtml in App_Code contain @@helpers

Comment: Gotcha, I personally think helpers are a terrible idea and I recommend using Editor or Display templates instead.  Sorry I can't help with this specific problem.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I would appreciate if you could elaborate a bit on how Editor or Display templates would replace @@helpers functionality? I could not find anything as easy to use in ASP.NET MVC 5 as @@helpers for composing html... Please see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986198/performance-considerations-with-nested-declarative-helpers-in-razor